# Divisibility of a binomial sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Convincing numerical evidence prompts me to ask:

> **Question.** Is $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}j^2\binom{2j}j(2j+1)^2$ divisible by $(n+1)^2$?

Comment: Is it clearly divisible by $n+1$?

Comment: That, too, is not clear. If proved, it might shade some light into the divisibility by $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: Empirically, $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k {k\ \choose j}^2 {2j \choose j} (2j+1) = (n+1)^2 \sum_{i = 0}^n {n \choose i}^2 C_i$, where $C_i$ is the $i$-th Catalan number.

Comment: @DannyRorabaugh: Is the lack of a square at the end of the LHS intentional?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: It's intentional because the identity is true only if you hold on to $(2j+1)$ on the LHS, not true with $(2j+1)^2$.

Comment: Also empirically, $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}j^2\binom{2j}j(2j+1)^{2p}$ also seems to be divisible by $\left(n+1\right)^2$ for any positive integer $p$.

Comment: possible duplicate with :http://mathoverflow.net/q/11335/51189

Comment: How is a "possible duplicate"? Please check carefully.

Comment: @darijgrinberg ...and divisible by $(n+1)$ but not $(n+1)^2$ for odd exponents greater than $1$.

Comment: This appears as (part of) Conjecture 5.6 in Zhi-Wei Sun "Two new kinds of numbers and related divisibility results", arXiv:1408.5381 v8. In Remark 5.3 Zhi-Wei Sun asserts it is divisible by  n+1.

Comment: @juan In a recent preprint, Sun's conjecture was proven by Mao: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06221.pdf (see Theorem 1.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the proof can be found in V. J. W. Guo, J.-C. Liu, Proof of some conjectures of Z.-W. Sun on the divisibility of certain double sums, Int. J. Number Theory 12 (2016), 615-623. An arXiv version is also [available](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5415).

Comment: Note: My conjecture seems to be the first claim of Conjecture 5.1 of that paper.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Yes, and this was proved by G.-S. Mao (https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06221).